# Prove that the class of dense linear orders cannot be axiomatized by purely universal sentenes

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, axioms

That is, prove that there is no set $T$ of purely universal sentences such that for every structure $A$ over the signature $\{\leq\}$, $A$ is a dense linear order iff $A\models T$.

Comment: Given a model of such a theory, consider whether a substructure must be a model as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there was such a set $T$. Clearly $(\mathbb{Q}, \le) \models T$, as it is a dense linear order.

$(\mathbb{Z}, \le)$ is a substructure of $(\mathbb{Q}, \le)$ so $T$ also holds in this, because purely universal sentences stay true on subsets: $(\mathbb{Z}, \le) \models T$.

But $(\mathbb{Z}, \le)$ is not a dense linear order, which contradicts the assumption on $T$.

Comment: Why the purely universal sentences are true on subsets?

Comment: @Gonzalo $\forall x \phi(x)$ holds for the larger set, so also for the smaller. Induct on the structure of the formula.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification